# How is Unicode different from ASCII?

Tags: unicode, unicode-string

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html. The below statement is from the this article:
"Some people are under the misconception that Unicode is simply a 16-bit code where each character takes 16 bits and therefore there are 65,536 possible characters. This is not, actually, correct. It is the single most common myth about Unicode". The author is trying to make a point that Unicode is not just "ASCII with more bytes"(extended ASCII), there is more to Unicode than just it appears. But I am not getting how Unicode is different? To me it appears as extended ASCII.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing what exactly your question is; can you clarify?

Comment: Some Unicode encodings have variable byte length. For example UTF-8, whose first 128 values are ASCII, and anything above is the first byte of a multi-byte character. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: There are many types of unicode. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Comment: The current Unicode version has 110,187 codepoints.  ~860 times more than ASCII, that is the difference.

Comment: Unicode is a character set with more than one encoding. ASCII is a character set with one encoding. (I _think_ that's what @RobertJacobs is alluding to.)

Comment: I have slightly modified the question. I guess I am a bit clear now.Hope so

Comment: I am loath to use such an ill-defined, ambiguous term such as "extended ASCII" but I'd say it implies a character set with an 8-bit encoding (with between 129 and 256 codepoints) that subsumes ASCII. So, Unicode is not extended ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

> As unicode has more numbers, it can map more characters.

Yes, that's it.

The ASCII character set defines a whopping 127 numbers, and specifies which characters they represent, and how they should be serialized as byte sequences. It says that each number should be encoded as a single byte, end of story.

Unicode has room for over a million such numbers, and specifies several different ways in which they may be serialized as byte sequences.

In addition, Unicode does quite a lot more than that - for example it doesn't just map integers to characters, it also maps characters to glyphs (the graphical symbols in a font), as well as describing various metadata for each character. But the main thing is just that Unicode defines a much bigger code space and separates the integer/character mapping from the encoding (so the same integer can be encoded as different byte sequences depending on whether you encode as UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32)

Comment: ASCII defines 128 codepoints numbered 0 to 127.

Comment: doh yeah, you're right of course

Answer (score 0):

Unicode assigns a unique integer to characters (and character modifiers).  There are many encodings, but common ones are UTF-16 and UTF-8, which are both variable-width encodings.

ASCII is a 1-byte encoding of a subset of characters.

Comment: UTF-16 is not a 2 byte encoding, but a variable width encoding just like UTF-8. That's exactly what Joel is trying to say.

Comment: @nwellnhof Thanks, you're right, of course.  UTF-16 is a 2-byte code unit encoding.  I've fixed the description.